# Batch create convenience : Ignore, overwrite, or error if some data has same value on DB?

Tags: usability, user-behavior

There should only one food menu for every single date.

I have a **single day** food create and a **weekly** one.

Usually in a scenario like this, it is common to throw an error saying that a data already exists.

I am thinking if a user created a *single food menu* for a day, and decided to use the *weekly food menu*, there is a chance that it might overlap it.

**My question now is:**

Is it fine to ignore it and process those that doesn't exists for convenience? And just give an information/warning message that a certain was ignored because it already exist?

**OR**

Should I just overwrite it?

But overwriting seems kinda inconvenient if the user forgot that he already made one for that day and overwrote it with the new one.

**BUT**

Is there by any chance you think they will forgot that they have already made one for a certain day? Or any reason that it really is inconvenient?

**OR**

Just stick to the usual and just throw an error and not process it first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've actually got two slightly views of the same data, rather than two bits of data fighting for precedence. I'd expect the weekly view to be pre-populated with any menus that have already been set for individual days and likewise for the daily view, if I edit/create a menu for a day that already has a menu set in the week view, I'd expect it to be pre-populated with that data.

Comment: but in the weekly creation, the user is asked what foods are on the menu on that day also. The difference is just, they are going to click the submit button once.

Comment: I see. In that situation I'd expect the weekly view to be pre-populated with any menus that have already been set for individual days and likewise for the daily view, if I edit/create a menu for a day that already has a menu set in the week view, I'd expect it to be pre-populated with that data.

Comment: wow, that's actually convenient just by imagining it. Let's see if others have more input. So far that is the best answer.